# What is the practical impact or use of a dodecagram?

Tags: theory, terminology, key, modulation

Looking for an answer about modulation and affects I came across with the term **"dodecagram"**.

So I was interested whether this has been already asked here, as I think it would be quite useful but I wonder how? Does it represent more than the simple keyboard pattern of the 12 keys and the circle of fifths as we know it? Do I miss something, or does it just look nice?[image: cle]

Answer (score 2):

The only added feature that I can see is the use of color.

The colors tend to be organized by proximity around a given key. C major, which is something like pink/red, is thus most closely aligned with G (pink/orange) and F (red/magenta). The further the two keys, the further their colors are.

To help visualize this, consult a color wheel:

[image]

We see that red is farthest from green, and sure enough, as opposites to the red of C and F, we have keys like F♯, B, and E.

Comment: I didn’t see the colors, interesting.

Answer (score -1):

The I, IV, and V chords for any given key are connected by the lines here. Although it's a little misleading. For example, the key of D major the I, IV, and V are D, A, and G (all major). You can see that D is connected by these lines to A and G. But this connection sort of looks like you would start on D and D, G and C. When in fact it's D, A, G. So you would change this to be closed isosceles triangles between the DAG to we that more clearly.

However the DGC connect does show perfect fifths. In fact, you can easily derive the circle of fifths from this picture by starting on B, beadgcf.

This image shows the order of the notes, the circle of 5ths and the I,IV, V (if you look at it the right way).

There's probably a lot more hidden on here. It's just counting by 4s or 5s or 3s repeated.

There is another way of drawing this where you get perfect 4ths and 4 cool overlapping triangles, but it's not as meaningful.

Finally if you use the top and number it 0 and go to 11, you can use clock math to know all the notes on a fretboard. For example, A is 0, F is 8, so the 8th fret of the A string will be F.

Comment: 1) Be aware that this question is ca 2 years old, and I think the OP understood how it's meant to work, and was asking "what's the point." 2) I think, when you say "it's misleading," you're mistaking what the chart is trying to do. It's not trying to help you move from IV to V, just to show the IV and the V of each I. 3) *"I, IV, and V are D, A, and G"* I think you meant to say "D, G, A"